# Is it safe to include passwords in client-side wasm code?

Tags: c#, webassembly, blazor

Since Wasm is written in non-human-readable form, does this make it nigh-on impossible for a hacker to look at the Wasm files of a site and figure out what's what?

I know it's never considered best practice to keep sensitive data on the client-side, but Wasm seems to be a bit of a game-changer when it comes to code obscurity (unless I've missed something somewhere).

Everything looks like this:

[image: In-browser Wasm files and code]

I don't see how any information can be gleaned from that.

For a bit of context, the reason I'm asking this is because I'm creating a password protected admin area for my Blazor website. I'm wondering if it's safe to deal with password entry entirely on the client side, simply for the joy of making the user experience that little bit faster (no need for a server call).

Code example below:

```
// page.razor

// C#

@functions{

    string password = "";

    private void Login()
    {
        if(password == "thisBeThePassword")
        {
            UriHelper.NavigateTo("/adminArea/" + password);
            //adminArea component recieves password as parameter for gaining access
        }
    }
}

// Razor/Blazor HTML

<input type="password" bind="@password"/>

<button onclick=@Login>Login</button>
```

Comment: wasm [can be decompiled to code](https://github.com/wwwg/wasmdec) so no I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Absolutely not, WASM can be decompiled

Comment: @stuartd Thanks, that pretty much answers my question!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6ci53i/clientside_security/

Answer (score 8):

Answers have come swiftly in the comments!

[WASM can be decompiled](https://github.com/wwwg/wasmdec), so no it's never a good idea to deal with sensitive information on the client-side.

Comment: I tried it and it gives me`/* Decompilation failed :( */` The file is http://worlddominationcommittee.org/~lee/filez/wasm/test5.wasm
However disassembly with wasm2wat works